# Declare not recognized under bash v4

Tags: mac, bash, ruby, rvm

I'm trying to make use of the new array/hash feature in bash version 4, but when I try to "declare" the variable, I'm getting an error.

```
$ bash --version
GNU bash, version 4.4.0(1)-release (x86_64-apple-darwin15.6.0)
Copyright (C) 2016 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>

This is free software; you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.

$ declare -A hello
-bash: declare: -A: invalid option
declare: usage: declare [-afFirtx] [-p] [name[=value] ...]

$ declare
...
rvm_warn ()
{
    if rvm_pretty_print stdout; then
        printf "%b" "${rvm_warn_clr:-}$*${rvm_reset_clr:-}\n" 1>&2;
    else
        printf "%b" "$*\n" 1>&2;
    fi
}
...
```

When I just type in "declare" it looks like ruby code.  I'm including a *very* small snippet from when I simply type in "declare".  I do have RVM installed.  Any ideas why I can't properly use "declare"?

Answer (score 1):

The options are case sensitive, and `-A` isn't a valid option (as shown in the usage list it presents - `[-afFirtx]`).

Use `-a` instead.

Comment: Thanks - just to clarify - following this tutorial: http://www.artificialworlds.net/blog/2012/10/17/bash-associative-array-examples/  the example shows a capitalized "A".  Must be a typo?